# How to add cooldown mapping to users who reacted first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Im currently working on a cart manager where users has a chance of a giveaway prize (First come first serve). Basically I will automatically post some embeds and the person who reacts first will get the prize and a message written in DM's from the bot. The user who got the prize first will get a cooldown for 5 minutes (the reason of this is that the same user should not be able to get a second prize within 5 minutes)

I have written something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from discord import Client, Embed, Object

client = Client()

lock = asyncio.Lock()

PRIVATE_CHANNEL_ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PUBLIC_CHANNEL_ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
EMOJI_ID = "\N{SHOPPING TROLLEY}"

# ----------------------------------------------------- #

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} Logged In!')

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == PUBLIC_CHANNEL_ID and '\U0001f6d2' == str(payload.emoji) and payload.user_id != client.user.id:
        async with lock:
            # Check if person is rate limited
```

I have read abit regarding cooldown mapping and found an example of:

```
class SomeCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cd = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1.0, 60.0, commands.BucketType.user)

    async def cog_check(self, ctx):
        bucket = self._cd.get_bucket(ctx.message)
        retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
        if retry_after:
            # you're rate limited
            # helpful message here
            pass
        # you're not rate limited
```

however my problem is that I do not know how to apply cooldown for a user who reacted first on given reaction and I wonder how can I do that? How can I apply a cooldown to the user to not be ablet o react for next 5 minutes using the `CooldownMapping`?

Comment: why do you need the lock for in the `on_raw_reaction_add` event?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Siema! Beacuse I will have multiple users who will click on the reaction button at the same time and I dont want it to overflood it and it should be handled one by one, so basically the first person who actually reacts should get the prize fairly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have shows how to have a common ratelimit between commands in a cog, to have a cooldown on the `on_raw_reaction_add` event you need a different approach.

```py
raw_reaction_add_cooldown = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(
    1, 60.0, commands.BucketType.user  # change rate and per accordingly
)


async def get_raw_reaction_add_ratelimit(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent) -> Optional[float]:
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    if guild is None or channel is None:
       return None

    author = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    if author is None or message is None:
        return None

    # overwriting author attribute since otherwise it will check the ratelimit 
    # of the user who SENT the message, not the one that reacted
    message.author = author
    bucket = raw_reaction_add_cooldown.get_bucket(message)
    return bucket.update_rate_limit()
```

To use it it's pretty simple, call the function and check for `None`

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    ratelimit = await get_raw_reaction_add_ratelimit(payload)
    if ratelimit is None:
        print("NO RATELIMIT")
    else:
        print("RATELIMIT")
```